# Can't launch windows phone app with a custom url scheme

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uri, url-scheme, custom-url

I'm trying to write an app that should be launched automatically when the user clicks on a link with a specific url (that should be something like "myscheme://myurl")

I followed the instructions on this link
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
However, it doesn't work

Here's what my code looks like

In the WMAppManifest.xml file I added this after the tokens

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="myscheme"
            NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s"
            TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

I then created a file that I named AssociationUriMapper.cs and that contains

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace PhoneApp3
{
    class AssociationUriMapper : UriMapperBase
    {
        private string tempUri;

        public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
        {
            tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());

            //URI association for my scheme
            if (tempUri.Contains("myscheme:"))
            {
                return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml");
           }

            //else return
            return uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the App.xaml.cs I added this line after the "rootframe.navigated"

```
// Assign the URI mapper to the frame
RootFrame.UriMapper = new AssociationUriMapper();
```

Now according to what I understood of the link that I included from msdn, if I go to internet explorer in the Windows Phone Simulator and type anything like "myscheme://something" it should automatically launch my app (even if the app does nothing provided that I don't manage to really use the url for now, I just want it to open my app)

I don't really now what to do, I found some other tutorials that explain exactly the same thing so I don't understand why my code doesn't work...

(BTW, sorry if I made grammar or spelling mistakes, English is not my mother tongue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [this tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/URI_associations_for_Windows_Phone).

Here is a  quote from it:

> What will trigger your URI association and launch your app: Get the
>   URI from NFC tag. Get the URI by mail.  Click on a HTML link
>   containing the URI.  Webpage redirection with a custom protocol.  Get
>   the URI from NFC device sharing an URI.

And another one:

> What will NOT trigger your URI association and launch your app:  Enter
>   directly the URI in the Web Browser.  Scan a QR code from Bing search.

So, entering the URI in the browser does NOT work. To test how your app behaves when launched from another app, you can download [Shortcuts](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appId=c0c3d676-9aaa-4d4a-9660-2966a637f072), make a shortcut to custom URI, and enter the URI you want to test there.

**Disclaimer:** I work at Enless Soft and Shortcuts is one of our apps.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem ! I just edited the url as a link in a html page and when I click on it, it launches my application as it should !

Answer (score 0):

So I added the code like described in the MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx to a Windows Phone 7.1 App

My steps were the same like Florian.C described. 
The problem now is, that if I add:

```
<Extensions>
    <Protocol Name="myApp" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

I get an error from VS, reporting that "Protocol" can not be a child of Extensions, it is expecting the child Extension. 
Is it possible to get the scheme running for OS 7.1?